# How to improve load time for a Silverlight app data display

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

Hi the initial data load for the Silverlight app, can take 6 -20 seconds. We are using web service, data is coming from one database and loads 2 years worth of transactions. We don't use summary tables.
Any ideas to look at for improving this loadtime? we are not doing insert/update/delete, just display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need 2 years of transactions right when the app loads? Maybe load just what you need to bring the UI up and then make the "heavier" call to load the 2 years of transactions in the background. What is the data format of your web service? Often times json payloads are going to be much smaller than xml.

Answer (score 0):

The same rules apply for Silverlight as web pages.  You want to lean out your data.  I would suggest using some kind of paging structure so that you are not loading all of the data at once.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to look at is loading the data in chunks so you can display something while you go off and load the rest.

If you use a DomainDataSource (as an example) you can set the load size and page size to get the first two or three "pages" of data initially and then as the user scrolls through the data load the rest.

Now this wouldn't work straight out of the box if you were displaying the data in a graph or some other non paged table.

However, you could use an ObservableCollection which would let you update and display asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the obvious answer will be to lean your data to small chunks. For a client technology like Silverlight we can’t guarantee that every user gets the best resources like network capacity, CPU etc. So what we can do is to limit the bandwidth usage and tune the data transfer effectively, which makes the server side implementation more important than the SL-client. So my point here is to address all the extensibility and performance concerns while at the designing of WebService. Other general tips to improve the performance could be

- Use Pagination across the service - Your service will pull appropriate set of info based on user action.
- Make use of Background thread if needed. Pulling down the data from Service or any parsing or deserialization can be offload to a thread.
- [Perceived performance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceived_performance) - Use some engaging animations and loading progress displays while the background thread does the data pulling. User will surely enjoy is there is a rhythm in the experience eventhough if it takes some time.